# How does this replaceAt function work?

Tags: javascript, string, function, methods, substring

Could you please explain how this piece of code works?

```
String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
    return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length);
};


function titleCase(str) {
    var newTitle = str.split(' ');
    var updatedTitle = [];
    for (var st in newTitle) {
        updatedTitle[st] = newTitle[st].toLowerCase().replaceAt(0, newTitle[st].charAt(0).toUpperCase());
    }
    return updatedTitle.join(' ');
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Specifically, what exactly is passed onto to replaceAt (I get that it's passed an index, and a character that's converted to lowercase), but what does replaceAt DO with it?

So, in the first iteration of the loop, it's passed replaceAt(0, i) right? Then what does replaceAt do with this? I just don't get this line:

`this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index+character.length)`

I've already read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr. I'm here because I don't understand that return statement and what exactly it's doing.

Comment: [`String.prototype.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: I've read this. I'm here because I don't understand how exactly the return statement is working.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? OP provided evidence that he/she has given some effort into understanding the code but came here to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you execute `"thisisatest".replaceAt(3, "h")`.

Then...

1. `this.substr(0, index)` returns `"thi"` : ie the first 3 characters of `"thisisatest"`
2. `character` returns `"h"`
3. `this.substr(index+character.length)` returns `"isatest"` : ie all characters of `"thisisatest"`, starting at position 4

So, when you combine this, you get `"thihisatest"`

Answer (score 1):

Lets imagine this easy case:

```
"0123456789". replaceAt(2/*index*/,"000"/*character*/)
```

Then this happens:

```
this.substr(0, index/*2*/)//"01"
 + character //"000"
 + this.substr(index/*2*/+character.length/*3*/)//"56789"
```

Output:

```
0100056789
```

Answer (score 0):

The replaceAt function simply takes the index of a character (0 in this case) and replaces it with another character (in this case the uppercase version of the original character. This specific function is just Title Casing a word by replacing the first character with the same character in uppercase.

The line that your questioning, takes a substring of the word before the character at the specificied index `this.substr(0,index)` since substr is non-inclusive of the last index, appends the specified character `+ character`, and appends a substr of the rest of the word `+ this.substr(index+character.length)`

Example 'testing'.replaceAt(0,`testing`.charAt(0).toUpperCase());
= '' + 'T' + 'esting' = Testing;

Answer (score 0):

`this.substr` is a function that operates on a string and returns a 'sub string' of the string. See a tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

So what `replaceAt` is doing is operating on a string and replacing the character at the target index, `index`, with the new substring, `character`. Indeed the passed `character` does not have to be only one character but could be multiple, like `abcd`. It is rather poorly named.

For more detail, using `substr()`, it is taking the first part of the string from index `0` to `index`, adding the 'character/string' passed to the function, and then taking the rest of the string from index `index+character.length` onwards. Note that `substr` has an optional parameter which is used in the first call (`this.substr(0,index)`).